# How to get an array size (and the biggest) with an SQL statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgres and some of my table's field are arrays.
I am looking for the biggest array is there any way to find this info with a SQL statement ?

```
CREATE TABLE chapter
(....
chapter_path integer[],
.....)
```

My chapter path are like that `{x,y,z} {x,y} {x}`

How with a SQL statement can I get **3** corresponding to `{x,y,z}` integer array size ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [array_upper()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, my arrays are arrays of uuid and not simple integer I put it up for the demo. Thanks anyway for the answer.

Comment: The array_lenght function of the page you gave me made the trick. Thank You !

Comment: @Frank , is there a difference between array_upper() and array_length() ?? Is there an advantage of using one over the other?
or are there situations where you must use one and not the other?